# How can I select dynamically from a datatable in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that groups and selects from a datatable (among other things). The select needs to be dynamically passed into the method if possible.

I tried passing a Func<...> to the method. I read other answers that suggest I might need to create a strong Type and possibly use generics to make it work.

```
var dtDistinct = dtRaw.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(g => g.Field<string>("DisplayName").ToString())
    .Select(group => new
    {
        DisplayName = group.Key,
        Value = string.Join("_", group.Select(s => s.Field<int>("Value"))),
        OrderBy = group.Max(s => s.Field<object>(columnNameToOrderBy).ToString())
    })
    .ToDataTable();
```

Everything in the above code will always be the case, except sometimes there may be additional columns in dtRaw that i need to select as well. These additional columns will not always have the same name or datatypes.

Comment: can't the type be obtained dynamically as well? you're grouping by object, which entails casting, which, depending on your use cases, might be expensive (computationally speaking).

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean?

Comment: unfortunately i cannot give you an example: I have dabbled in Reflection so I am vaguely aware that it might be an option, but I am not in a position to give you an educated answer, but perhaps it's worth looking into. Just search for "reflection c#" with your preferred search engine and it should come up with some relevant results opening up some options because reflection is all about determining and setting types dynamically.